# Use case of Observable .do() operator (rxjs)

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, observable, angularfire2

#### Context :

I'm building an angular 2 app (with a Firebase API). I'm using the AngularFire module. I was wondering how I can mix the `canActivate` method with the AngularFire auth Observable, and I found [this post](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/282). The answer is to make the `canActivate` method returns an `Observable<boolean>` :

```
canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.auth
    .take(1)
    .map((authState: FirebaseAuthState) => !!authState)
    .do(authenticated => {
      if (!authenticated) this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    });
}
```

It's the first time I see the Observable `do` operator, and I can't understand what it really does ? The official doc didnt help me, and I didn't found decent examples.

#### Question:

Can someone bring here some examples of `.do()` usage ? And difference with `.subscribe()` ?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

**Update**

Now it's `pipe( tap(...), )` instead of `do()`

**Original**

`.do()` is to execute code for each event. A difference to `.map()` is, that the return value of `.do()` is ignored and doesn't change what value the subscriber receives.

Comment: OK I see, it's for doing some treatment without modify the stream. But I don't get why this work without a `subscribe` ? Does `do` do the same ? Can you give me some examples ? Thx for your reply anyway

Comment: @Soywod There is a subscribe: just not in your code. The router subscribes to the observable returned by your guard, to know if it can activate or not.

Comment: So am I correct in saying that the side effect in the do() call will get executed after the router Subscriber function ?

Comment: @user2153465 `router.navigate` will be called when the observable returned by `this.auth` emits the first value.

Comment: Can I use an observable wit do without sharing the observable?

Comment: @Franki1986 sure, but you need to `subscribe()` otherwise the executable won't do anything and also not call `do(...)`.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer. Is `do` operator still present in `RxJS`. I was going through the documentaion today and could not find it. If it is removed, is there any replacement for this operator.

Comment: It's `tap()` now

Answer (score 8):

Now it's `pipe( tap(...), )` instead of `do()`

```
const source = of(1, 2, 3, 4);
source.pipe(
  tap(val => console.log('I am tap: ',val)),
  filter(val =>  val > 2),
  map(val => val + 1)).subscribe((val) => {
  console.log('I am subscriber value after filtering: ', val);
});
```

**Output:**

```
I am tap:  1
I am tap:  2
I am tap:  3
I am subscriber value after filtering:  4
I am tap:  4
I am subscriber value after filtering:  5
```

*Tap operator doesn't modify anything, you can say that it is just to view the stream.